# Groovy returning an array for each match

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have strings in my logs in following pattern `output:server-01-logs_20190401162454`, `output:database-01-logs_20190401162454`. I need to match the string before the underscore(`_`) i.e **output:database-01-logs** and **output:server-01-logs**. So I am using the following pattern:

```
result = text =~ /output:([^_]+)/
Iterator<String> elements = result.iterator();
while (elements.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(elements.next());
}
```

But the result I am getting is an array of match for each String like below

```
[output:server-01-logs, server-01-logs]
[output:database-01-logs, database-01-logs]
```

What I expect is

```
output:server-01-logs
output:database-01-logs
```

Can somebody help me with what I am missing here?

Comment: you have groups in regexp, so you got array - whole match + each group. just take first element from each match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may remove the capturing group (since it appears you do not want to get any submatches) and use

```
def text = "output:server-01-logs_20190401162454, output:database-01-logs_20190401162454"
def result = (text =~ /output:[^_]+/).collect()
```

See [this Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/80CgkO).

Or, if you want to preserve the capturing group, collect Group 0 values:

```
def text = "output:server-01-logs_20190401162454, output:database-01-logs_20190401162454"
def result = (text =~ /output:([^_]+)/).collect { it[0] }
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[output:server-01-logs, output:database-01-logs]
```

See [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/kWcw7k).

If you need the *captured* values, replace `it[0]` with `it[1]`.